# Add Social Login with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to integrate Multiple Social Login (like Facebook,Twitter,Linkedin) in my Spring Security project.

I am guessing i will have to make some changes here:

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("123456").roles("USER");

    }
```

I am not sure what changes will i have to make ,if i authenticate vai a DB service ,i understand i will be using :

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

But what to do in case we want to authenticate against Facebook,Twitter,Linkedin etc.Do i create a wrapper service ,but how would it really work as the workflow would go to twitter,FB and there would be a callback.

**NOTE: I don't want to use Spring Social**